# How to bundle a "frozen" version of mypy with an application

Tags: mypy, transcrypt

We are using mypy as typechecker in the [Transcrypt](http://www.transcrypt.org) Python to JavaScript compiler.
Since mypy is still in flux, we bundle a "frozen" version with Transcrypt, to prevent incompatibilities due to changes in mypy.

Upto now we've included version 0.4.4 in a subdirectory of the Transcrypt installation dir, and it worked fine.

Now we're trying to upgrade to 0.4.7, but in typechecking this simple test program:

```
def f (i: int) -> int:
    return 'xyz'

f ('abc')

def g (i: int) -> int:
    return 'xyz'

f ('abc')
```

we get the following error messages:

```
test.py: error: Name '__builtins__' is not defined
test.py:1: error: Name 'int' is not defined
```

If we just use the regularly installed mypy, everything goes fine and the following report is shown:

```
test.py:2: error: Incompatible return value type (got "str", expected "int")
test.py:4: error: Argument 1 to "f" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
test.py:7: error: Incompatible return value type (got "str", expected "int")
test.py:9: error: Argument 1 to "f" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
```

It seems that mypy needs some facilities to be in a special location.
We already tried the `custom-typeshed-dir` option but that didn't help.

Can anyone shed light on how to bundle mypy with an application?